# Find Gaps in Date Ranges using sql in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql, gaps-and-islands

I need to find Gaps between DateRanges of base and test ranges using sql.here is my example
SD and ED are start and End Dates. all rows for both A and B are in same table.

**A's Date**

```
ID    SD            ED
 A   20130101      20130531
 A   20130601      20131031
```

**B's Date**

```
 ID  SD            ED
 B   20130120      20130420
 B   20130601      20130830
 B   20130910      20131130
```

> ```
> Output should be: 
> the Dates that are in A but are not in B with no dates overlaps
> ```

**Missing Gap Ranges**

```
SD           ED
20130101     20130119
20130421     20130531
20130831     20130909
```

i looked at some example in here
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:529176000346581356
but they did not scenario like mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
   to_char(SD, 'yyyymmdd') as SD,
   to_char(ED, 'yyyymmdd') as ED
from
   (  -- prepare gaps in each A after removing all B
      select
         BED + 1 as SD,
         lead(BSD, 1, AED + 1) over (partition by ASD,AED order by BSD) - 1 as ED
      from
         (  -- prepare all intersections between A and B
            select AA.sd as ASD, AA.ed as AED, BB.sd as BSD, BB.ed as BED
            from AA join BB on least(AA.ed, BB.ed) >= greatest(AA.sd, BB.sd)
            union all
            select AA.sd, AA.ed, to_date('1000','yyyy'), AA.sd - 1
            from AA
         )
   )   
where SD <= ED  -- exclude empty gaps
order by 1
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da18c/3)

Comment: this is great. Thanks a Lot!!!!. my data is integer and not date in Db and in a single table , can you add comments on this as to what is doing what in here its pretty cool sql but not sure how its working

Comment: @NatashaThapa - To convert number to date: `to_date(number, 'yyyymmdd')`, to convert date to number: `to_number(to_char(date, 'yyyymmdd'))`

Comment: could you please add some comments as to what each section of sql is doing if i have to change

Comment: how to handle if you have an overlap in A to begin with and you want to avoid that overlap in B